# Pass array elements containing whitespace to Zenity window

Tags: bash

I'm trying to build a bash script that, when executed, gets all the **directories** from a specific path and displays them in a Zenity list window. From that window, the user selects a directory name via a radio-button and submits his selection.

First, here's my bash script:

```
projectTypes=(~/application1/Snippets/Project\ Type/*/)
radioStates=()

for index in "${!projectTypes[@]}"; do
    if [[ "$index" = "0" ]]; then
        folderName=$(basename "${projectTypes[$index]}")
        projectTypes[$index]="$folderName"
        radioStates[$index]=TRUE
    else    
        folderName=$(basename "${projectTypes[$index]}")
        projectTypes[$index]="$folderName"
        radioStates[$index]=FALSE
    fi
done

PROJTYPE=$( zenity \
    --list --radiolist \
    --title="Project Type" --text="Please select project type:" \
    --column="Select" --column="Project Type" \
    $( \
        for index in "${!projectTypes[@]}"; do
            printf "%s %s " "${radioStates[$index]}" "${projectTypes[$index]}"
        done
    ) \
)
```

So I'm trying to retrieve the names of all the **directories** found in the "Project Type" folder. Inside the "Project Type" folder I've got the following directories:

```
~/application1/Snippets/Project Type/Angular 2/   
~/application1/Snippets/Project Type/PrestaShop/ 
~/application1/Snippets/Project Type/WordPress/
```

Now I managed to get the directories' names correctly as *"Angular 2"*, *"PrestaShop"* and *"WordPress"* but I cannot correctly output them to the Zenity list window.

```
Expected Output:

SELECT | PROJECT TYPE
---------------------
(*)    | Angular 2
( )    | PrestaShop
( )    | WordPress

Current erroneous output:

SELECT | PROJECT TYPE
---------------------
(*)    | Angular
( )    | FALSE
( )    | FALSE
( )    |
```

[Current erroneous output - Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqO6n.png)

I can assume that the problem is the way I'm trying to expand the array elements but after hours of researching and trial and error, I haven't been able to identify how I should do it.

In any case, I greatly appreciate any help!

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solving the Problem

The problem is that `zenity` needs the arguments `zenity ... "Angular 2" ...` but reads `zenity ... "Angular" "2"`. To avoid this we could create an array which holds the arguments for `zenity` and expand that in a safe way:

```
# ...

argList=()
for (( i = 0; i < "${#projectTypes[@]}"; ++i )); do
    argList[2*i]="${radioStates[i]}"
    argList[2*i + 1]="${projectTypes[i]}"
done

PROJTYPE=$( zenity \
    --list --radiolist \
    --title="Project Type" --text="Please select project type:" \
    --column="Select" --column="Project Type" \
    "${argList[@]}" \
)
```

## Improving the Existing Code

Since you only want to set the first entry to true, you can omit the array `radioStates` and write

```
argList=()
for (( i = 0; i < "${#projectTypes[@]}"; ++i )); do
    argList[2*i]=FALSE
    argList[2*i + 1]="${projectTypes[i]}"
    argList[0]=TRUE
done
```

`argList[0]=TRUE` is inside the loop to make sure that `argList` stays empty if `projectTypes` is empty. We will assign multiple times, but saved an if statement in return.

Comment: That works beautifully and is a lot more readable. Thank you!

I was trying to avoid having two _types_ of data in the same array (boolean and string) so that's why I was using two arrays. Is it common practice to populate an array with multiple types of data as in your solution?

Comment: I wouldn't say that it is *the* standard solution, but your problem is also not a problem I'm facing normally. However all array entries have the same type, which is *string*. Bash supports [different types](https://linux.die.net/Bash-Beginners-Guide/sect_10_01.html) but has no boolean type. Most people just stick to the default string type anyway.